# Python - how to separate paragraphs from text?

Tags: python, paragraph

I need to separate texts into paragraphs and be able to work with each of them. How can I do that? Between every 2 paragraphs can be at least 1 empty line. Like this:

```
Hello world,
  this is an example.

Let´s program something.


Creating  new  program.
```

Comment: Assuming the text is in a text file. Read the file line wise and whenever you encounter a blank line, you know that whatever was above that line belonged to a paragraph. Extend this similarly for upcoming text.

Comment: This is clear for me, but I need a help with syntax, how to write this.

Comment: @kom20 do you know how to open a file and read a line? What difficultly do you have specifically ?

Comment: I know this, but I need to align all paragraphs for set width of characters and for that I need to separate paragraphs from the text and work with each individually.

Answer (score 8):

This sould work:

```
text.split('\n\n')
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems good. But since the end of the text consists of some empty lines, last items in this list are empty (like this): ["something","",""]. Can this make any problem as soon as I get into work with the particular words in these paragraphs?

Comment: This is for you to say. You can always filter them out with `filter(None, ...)`

Comment: The question specifies "at least one empty line", so this solution is not entirely correct on its own. For instance, "one\n\n\n\n\ntwo\n".split("\n\n") is not super pretty.

Comment: Nope, it is not sufficient. \n\n\n is a valid separator, so should be \n\t\20\n\t\t\n

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
result = list(filter(lambda x : x != '', text.split('\n\n')))
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.

Comment: I think it would be more pythonic to write this as a list comprension, instead of using filter + lambda. Also, split("\n\n") does not work cleanly if paragraphs are separated by more than a single empty line.

Answer (score 2):

Not an entirely trivial problem, and the standard library doesn't seem to have any ready solutions.

Paragraphs in your example are split by *at least* two newlines, which unfortunately makes `text.split("\n\n")` invalid. I think that instead, splitting by regular expressions is a workable strategy:

```py
import fileinput
import re

NEWLINES_RE = re.compile(r"\n{2,}")  # two or more "\n" characters

def split_paragraphs(input_text=""):
    no_newlines = input_text.strip("\n")  # remove leading and trailing "\n"
    split_text = NEWLINES_RE.split(no_newlines)  # regex splitting

    paragraphs = [p + "\n" for p in split_text if p.strip()]
    # p + "\n" ensures that all lines in the paragraph end with a newline
    # p.strip() == True if paragraph has other characters than whitespace

    return paragraphs

# sample code, to split all script input files into paragraphs
text = "".join(fileinput.input())
for paragraph in split_paragraphs(text):
    print(f"<<{paragraph}>>\n")
```

Edited to add:

It is probably cleaner to use a state machine approach. Here's a fairly simple example using a generator function, which has the added benefit of streaming through the input one line at a time, and not storing complete copies of the input in memory:

```py
import fileinput

def split_paragraph2(input_lines):
    paragraph = []  # store current paragraph as a list
    for line in input_lines:
        if line.strip():  # True if line is non-empty (apart from whitespace)
            paragraph.append(line)
        elif paragraph:  # If we see an empty line, return paragraph (if any)
            yield "".join(paragraph)
            paragraph = []
    if paragraph:  # After end of input, return final paragraph (if any)
        yield "".join(paragraph)

# sample code, to split all script input files into paragraphs
for paragraph in split_paragraph2(fileinput.input()):
    print(f"<<{paragraph}>>\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually split then filter out the '' and strip. ;)

```
a =\
'''
Hello world,
  this is an example.

Let´s program something.


Creating  new  program.


'''

data = [content.strip() for content in a.splitlines() if content]

print(data)
```

Comment: This does not actually split into paragraphs. It splits into non-empty lines.
The first two lines in this example should be in the same paragraph!

Comment: I did not know that is a requirement;)

Answer (score 0):

this is worked for me:

```
text = "".join(text.splitlines())
text.split('something that is almost always used to separate sentences (i.e. a period, question mark, etc.)')
```

Answer (score -1):

Easier. I had the same problem.

Just replace the double \n\n entry by a term that you seldom see in the text (here ¾):

---

```py
a ='''
Hello world,
  this is an example.

Let´s program something.


Creating  new  program.'''
a = a.replace("\n\n" , "¾")

splitted_text = a.split('¾')

print(splitted_text)
```